# Why does float.ToString("F15") drop precision although it has enough digits?

Tags: .net, floating-point

I thought that `float.ToString("F15")` has enough digits to not drop precision, but it does drop precision:

```
float f = 0.105700679f;
Console.WriteLine(f == 0.105700679f); //True
Console.WriteLine(f == 0.1057007f); //False
Console.WriteLine(f.ToString("F15")); //0.105700700000000
Console.WriteLine(f.ToString("R")); //Round-trip format: 0.105700679
```

It appears that the `F` format is not round-trippable to the same value even though there are enough digits available to precisely represent the value. I'm running this on.NET 4.7.1. Can somebody shed some light onto this? Is this a bug?

The unfortunate thing about this is that different float values convert to identical strings:

```
float f1 = 0.105700657f;
float f2 = 0.105700679f;

Console.WriteLine(f1.ToString("F15")); //0.105700700000000
Console.WriteLine(f2.ToString("F15")); //0.105700700000000
```

You can use https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html to confirm that these float constants are indeed different IEEE float values. So it's not just a compile time loss of precision.

Comment: Not a complete answer as it doesn't explain the behavior, but `float` only supports a max of 7 digits of precision. If you need more than 7 digits of precision then use `double` instead. Ir if you need _exact_ base-10 representations use `decimal`.

Comment: Thanks D Stanley! I'm fighting with a data source sending me financial prices as floats... Bad idea but I need to deal with it.

Comment: Also this warning from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings): "For Double and Single values, the "R" format specifier in some cases fails to successfully round-trip the original value and also offers relatively poor performance. Instead, we recommend that you use the "G17" format specifier for Double values and the "G9" format specifier to successfully round-trip Single values."

Comment: @DStanley You should move your comment to an answer. It does, actually, answer the question. It's just a surprising answer.

Comment: @MikeHofer Sure, but I was also curious why `ToString("R")` kept the extra digits - maybe that's the bug and why it's not recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possibly due to known limitations (bugs?) in the ["R" standard format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-round-trip-r-format-specifier) for floating point types:

> For `Double` and `Single` values, the "R" format specifier in some cases fails to successfully round-trip the original value and also offers relatively poor performance. Instead, we recommend that you use the "G17" format specifier for `Double` values and the "G9" format specifier to successfully round-trip `Single` values.

I would also note that decimal only guarantees 7 digits of precision, so the results you show are not completely unexpected (both `f1` and `f2` round to the same number given 7 digits of precision).

Comment: The `"G9"` specifier works! Shame that these bugs are allowed to live. The decimal documentation says `28-29 significant digits`. decimal is also a floating point format, but with base 10 instead of base 2.

Comment: @boot4life bugs are not free to fix - the C# team must weigh the benefit versus the cost of fixing that bug versus other bugs or new features.  My guess is that there have not been enough complaints about it to make it worth the time to design, implement, test, document, and support a fix.