# How to not drop precision when converting from float to decimal in a case where this is clearly possible

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, decimal

The value `0.105700679f` should be convertible precisely to `decimal`. `decimal` clearly is able to hold this value precisely:

```
decimal d = 0.105700679m;
Console.WriteLine(d); //0.105700679
```

`float` also is able to hold the value precisely:

```
float f = 0.105700679f;
Console.WriteLine(f == 0.105700679f); //True
Console.WriteLine(f == 0.1057007f); //False
Console.WriteLine(f.ToString("R")); //Round-trip representation, 0.105700679
```

(Note, that `float.ToString()` seems to drop precision. [I just asked about that as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522464/why-does-float-tostringf15-drop-precision-although-it-has-enough-digits))

https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html says:

[image]

It seems the value really is stored like that. I am seeing this value right now in the debugger. I received it over the network as IEEE float. This value exists!

But when I convert from float to decimal precision is dropped:

```
float f = 0.105700679f;
decimal d = (decimal)f;
Console.WriteLine(d); //0.1057007
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("F15")); //0.105700700000000
Console.WriteLine(((double)d).ToString("R")); //0.1057007
```

I do understand that floating point numbers are imprecise. But here I see no reason for a loss of information. This is on .NET 4.7.1. How can I convert from float to decimal and preserve precision in all cases where doing so is possible?

This is important to me because I am processing financial market data and joining data sources based on price. Data is given to me as a `float` over a 3rd party network protocol. I need to import that `float` to a `decimal` representation.

Comment: There's no such number as `0.105700679f`. It can't be represented as an IEEE floating point number (whether double or single precision). It falls inbetween actual existing binary FP numbers (in the same way that 1/3 can't be represented in decimal). You will **always** have imprecision when making such conversions over all but a small subset of fractional values.

Comment: @spender I added some code from my other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522464/why-does-float-tostringf15-drop-precision-although-it-has-enough-digits). What do you think of that? It seems float can hold this value.

Comment: No. float can't hold this specific value, in the same way that float (or double) can't ever hold the precise value of `0.1`.

Comment: @spender But it *can* hold 0.5 precisely for example. Please see the image that I just added. What's your opinion on that?

Comment: `0.5` **can** be represented precisely as an FP number, as can 0.25, or 0.125. However, 0.1 **cannot** be represented precisely as an FP number. You really should read up about this rather than arguing with me. http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: The real problem here is that someone up the chain messed up by making the schoolboy error of using FP numbers for financial data, and you've been left holding the crappy end of the stick. FP numbers are wholy unsuitable for financial (decimal) calculations.

Comment: @spender you are right with that. I still need to solve the issue, though, and it seems possible. The source data absolutely has the information that I need. Maybe I just don't know how to correctly use the .NET Framework APIs. The core problem is that unequal prices must compare as unequal after the conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try converting `f` to `double` and then converting that to decimal.

I suspect you are seeing shortcomings in .NET.

Let’s look at some of the code in your question line by line. In `float f = 0.105700679f;`, the decimal numeral “0.105700679” is converted to 32-bit binary floating-point. The result of this is the number 0.105700679123401641845703125.

In `Console.WriteLine(f == 0.105700679f);`. This compares `f` to the value represented by `0.105700679f`. Since the `f` suffix denotes a `float` type, `0.105700679f` represents the decimal numeral “0.105700679” converted to 32-bit binary floating-point. So of course it has the same value as it did before, and the test for equality returns true. You have not tested whether `f` is equal to 0.105700679, you have tested whether it is equal to `0.105700679f`, and it is.

Then we have `decimal d = (decimal)f;`. Based on the results you are seeing, it appears to me this conversion produces a number with only seven decimal digits, .1057007. I presume Microsoft has decided that, because a `float` is only “capable” of holding seven decimal digits, that only seven should be produced when converting to decimal. (This is both a false understanding of what the value of a binary floating-point number represents and an incorrect number. A conversion from decimal to `float` and back is only guaranteed to preserve six decimal digits, and a conversion from `float` to decimal and back requires nine decimal digits to preserve the `float` value. So seven is just wrong.)

If there is a solution to your problem, it is to convert `f` to decimal by some means other than the cast `(decimal) f`. I do not know C#, so I cannot say what the solution should be. I suggest trying to convert to `double` first and then decimal. Quite likely C# will convert `float` to `double` without changing the value, and then the conversion to decimal will produce more decimal digits. Another possibility could be converting `f` to a string with the number of decimal digits you desire and then converting the string to a decimal number.

Also, you say the data is coming via a third-party network protocol. It appears the protocol is incapable of representing the actual values it is supposed to be communicating. That is a serious defect that you should complain to the third party about. I know that may seem futile, but it should be done. Also, it casts doubt on your need to convert the float value to `0.105700679`. Most eight-digit decimal numbers in the origin of this data could not survive the conversion to `float` and back to decimal without change. So, even if you are able to convert `float` to eight decimal digits, most of the results will differ from the original pre-transport values. E.g., if the original number were 0.105700680, it is changed to 0.105700679123401641845703125 when converted to a `float` to be sent over the network. So the receiver receives 0.105700679123401641845703125, and it is impossible for them to know the original number was 0.105700680 rather than 0.105700679.

Comment: Competent answer! Also good point with regard to pre-transport conversion loss. I ended up with this: `static decimal ImportPrice(float f) => Decimal.Round((decimal)(double)f, 8, MidpointRounding.ToEven)`. This is a hack. It works for me but might not work for others. The conversion to double was necessary as was the rounding to 8 digits. I don't need more than 8 digits.

Answer (score -2):

C# data type FLOAT have Precision is 7.

```
float f = 0.105700679f;
Console.WriteLine(d); //0.1057007 so that result is true!
```

read more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/float

Comment: This is, in my opinion, misformatting, which I asked about a minute ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522464/why-does-float-tostringf15-drop-precision-although-it-has-enough-digits

Comment: The float type has a precision of 24 *bits*, not 7 decimal digits. The number of digits you see is just an artifact of the string conversion code, not of the float type itself.

Comment: Even if you are measuring the precision of binary floating-point in units of decimal digits, seven is wrong. The number of significant decimal digits that can always be converting to `float` and back to decimal without change is six. And the number of decimal digits required to ensure that a `float` can be converted to decimal and back without change is nine.